# XCode parameters for creating apps for Mac OS Tiger, Leopard, Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm currently building an app that needs to be runnable on Tiger, Leopard and Snow Leopard. I'm working in Xcode 3.2.3 and my machine has OS 10.6.4.

What parameters do I need to change for the separate builds? In the old Xcode I could just change the tab in the upper left hand corner from 10.4 to 10.5. Now there are just options for  x86_64, i386 and ppc which I'm not exactly clear about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it!

In Xcode go to the menu tab **Project** then **Edit Project Settings** (which is near the bottom) then go to the tab **Build**.

Comment: Make sure you set these at the top level (project) and for all build configurations (i.e. Debug and Release).

Answer (score 0):

Set the SDK to 10.4u and gcc version to 4.0. If you didn't install the older SDKs when you installed Xcode then go back and do that.

Comment: I have installed the older SDKs. Where do I set the SDK to 10.4 and the gcc version to 4.0? Preferences?